# One single-batch training on Huggingface Bert model "ruins" the model

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

For some reason, I need to do further (2nd-stage) pre-training on Huggingface Bert model, and I find my training outcome is very bad.

After debugging for hours, surprisingly, I find even training one single batch after loading the base model, will cause the model to predict a very bad choice when I ask it to unmask some test sentences. I boil down my code to the minimal reproducible version here:

```py
import torch
from transformers import AdamW, BertTokenizer
from transformers import BertForPreTraining

MSK_CODE = 103
CE_IGN_IDX = -100 # CrossEntropyLoss ignore index value

def sanity_check(tokenizer, inputs):
    print(tokenizer.decode(inputs['input_ids'][0]))
    print(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(
        inputs["labels"][0]
    ))
    print('Label:', inputs["next_sentence_label"][0])

def test(tokenizer, model, topk=3):
    test_data = "She needs to [MASK] that [MASK] has only ten minutes."
    print('\n \033[92m', test_data, '\033[0m')
    test_inputs = tokenizer([test_data],
                       padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
    def classifier_hook(module, inputs, outputs):
        unmask_scores, seq_rel_scores = outputs
        token_ids = test_inputs['input_ids'][0]
        masked_idx = (
            token_ids == torch.tensor([MSK_CODE])
        )
        scores = unmask_scores[0][masked_idx]
        cands = torch.argsort(scores, dim=1, descending=True)
        for i, mask_cands in enumerate(cands):
            top_cands = mask_cands[:topk].detach().cpu()
            print(f'MASK[{i}] top candidates:', end=" ")
            print(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(top_cands))
    classifier = model.cls
    hook = classifier.register_forward_hook(classifier_hook)
    model.eval()
    model(**test_inputs)
    hook.remove()
    print()

# load model
model = BertForPreTraining.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3, weight_decay=0.01)

# first test
test(tokenizer, model)

# our single-iteration inputs
#   [CLS]  1   2   3   4   5   6   [SEP]  8      9    10  11    12  [SEP]
pair = [['the man went to the store', 'penguins are flightless birds']]
relation_label = 1

# construct inputs
inputs = tokenizer(pair, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
inputs["next_sentence_label"] = torch.tensor([relation_label])
mask_labels = torch.full(inputs["input_ids"].shape, fill_value=CE_IGN_IDX)
inputs["labels"] = mask_labels

# mask two words
inputs["input_ids"][0][4] = MSK_CODE
inputs["input_ids"][0][9] = MSK_CODE
mask_labels[0][4] = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids('to')
mask_labels[0][9] = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids('are')

# train for one single iteration
sanity_check(tokenizer, inputs)
model.train()
optimizer.zero_grad()
outputs = model(**inputs)
loss = outputs.loss
loss.backward(loss)
optimizer.step()

# second test
test(tokenizer, model)
```

output:

```sh
Some weights of BertForPreTraining were not initialized from the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased and are newly initialized: ['cls.predictions.decoder.bias']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.

  She needs to [MASK] that [MASK] has only ten minutes. 
MASK[0] top candidates: ['know', 'understand', 'remember']
MASK[1] top candidates: ['she', 'he', 'it']

[CLS] the man went [MASK] the store [SEP] penguins [MASK] flightless birds [SEP]
['[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', 'to', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', 'are', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]']
Label: tensor(1)

  She needs to [MASK] that [MASK] has only ten minutes. 
MASK[0] top candidates: ['are', 'know', 'be']
MASK[1] top candidates: ['are', 'is', 'she']
```

Basically, I use `She needs to [MASK] that [MASK] has only ten minutes.` as a test sentence to test the unmasking.
As you may see, at the beginning when I tested the base model, it works perfectly.
However, after I feed the pre-train model with a single pair of training batch:

`[CLS] the man went [MASK] the store [SEP] penguins [MASK] flightless birds [SEP]`

The updated model no longer makes sense, it unmasks `She needs to [MASK] that [MASK] has only ten minutes.` into `She needs to [are] that [are] has only ten minutes.`

I can think of two possibilities why this happens...

1. Bert model is extremely sensitive to training batch size, a small batch causes unacceptable bias.
2. there is a bug in the code?

So, any idea?

Comment: I haven't checked your code, but your learning rate is pretty high. The BERT authors recommended a learning rate of `5e-5`, `3e-5` or `2e-5`.

Comment: @cronoik thank you so much. Yea, I used the recommended lr for pretraining, while what I am doing is technically "finetune", even though it is doing things similar to MLM and NSP. I am running a new training to test it out... buf for now I guess that is the most likely reason.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you consider it as finetuning. The numbers are telling you that transformers are sensitive and even a single batch with such a comparatively high learning rate will change a lot. Even in terms of pretraining, your learning rate is high compare to the BERT paper learning rate of `1e-4`.

Comment: @cronoik yup, it turns out lr being too high is exactly the issue. Thanks for your comment, this question is actually solved. Though I also tried the documented 1e-4, it still looks destructive after millions of steps. Also, pertaining from scratch is still hard from my setting even after I lower the learning rate to 1e-6 to 1e-7.